# Parse: A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: parse-platform

Without having made any changes, I am suddenly encountering a failure to locate the Parse API URL.

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x1557a3d0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/client_events, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/client_events, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x1556e470 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.4.1)
```

I saw some old threads about this but the fault was Parse's - a DNS issue - and all threads were closed without resolution. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please read the descriptions of tags: parse.com is *correct*, parsing is unrelated.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.  For Parse folks,  why did I get this DNS error for hours today? (Its gone now), but its worrisome as I am building a lot on this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Experiencing the same thing right now.. did you ever get a resolution to this?

Comment: Its Happening to me to  now...

Comment: same for me. How did you guys solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a temporary server/network issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: same for me. How did you guys solve it?